# Spring MVC and LightBox

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, lightbox

I would like to use a **lightbox** to display my forms, i have used **Fancybox** and was not successful. I would like some advice on the best **lightbox** plugin to use to achieve this and how would i need to set this up since my form request will go thru the Controller first.

**Updated:**

This form work fine without the lightbox. The Controller is working when i click on the link it just takes me to the page and doesn't display the form in the lightbox.

**Code:**

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
            <%@ include file="../js/lightbox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"%>

    </script>


    <style>
            <%@ include file="../js/lightbox/jquery.fancybox.css" %>

    </style>    

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });
    </script>


  <title><fmt:message key="title"/></title>



  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><fmt:message key="heading"/></h1>
    <p><fmt:message key="greeting"/></p>


    <a href="<c:url value="login.htm"/>">Login</a></br>



    <a href="<c:url value="officer_registration.htm"/>">Register</a></br>


    <a class="fancybox" href="officer_registration.htm">Light Box Registration</a></br>
    <a class="fancybox" href="http://en.gtwallpaper.com/fondecran/chiens/chiens_01.jpg" >dog</a>


   </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">
            <%@ include file="../js/lightbox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"%>

    </script>


    <style>
            <%@ include file="../js/lightbox/jquery.fancybox.css" %>

    </style>    

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#regForm').click(function() {
                $.fancybox({
                        'href' : '/officer_registration.htm'
                    });

                return false;
            });

            $('#pic').click(function() {
                $.fancybox({
                        'href' : 'http://en.gtwallpaper.com/fondecran/chiens/chiens_01.jpg'
                    });

                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>


  <title><fmt:message key="title"/></title>



  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><fmt:message key="heading"/></h1>
    <p><fmt:message key="greeting"/></p>


    <!--  <a href="<c:url value="login.htm"/>">Login</a></br> -->   
    <!-- <a href="<c:url value="officer_registration.htm"/>">Register</a></br>  -->

    <!-- <a class="fancybox" href="login.htm">Light Box login</a></br>  -->

    <a id="regForm" class="fancybox" href="officer_registration.htm">Light Box Registration</a></br>

    <!-- <a id ="pic" class="fancybox" href="http://en.gtwallpaper.com/fondecran/chiens/chiens_01.jpg" >dog</a>  This picture works presently-->


   </body>
</html>
```

**EDITED HTML at runtime**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

  <head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

   <!--  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script> -->



    <script type="text/javascript">
            /*! fancyBox v2.1.2 fancyapps.com | fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license */


.......... 


    </script>


    <style>
            /*! fancyBox v2.1.2 fancyapps.com | fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license */
.fancybox-wrap,
.fancybox-skin,
.fancybox-outer,
.fancybox-inner,
.fancybox-image,
.fancybox-wrap iframe,
.fancybox-wrap object,
.fancybox-nav,
.fancybox-nav span,
.fancybox-tmp
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.fancybox-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 8020;
}

.fancybox-skin {
    position: relative;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    color: #444;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
}

.fancybox-opened {
    z-index: 8030;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-skin {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.fancybox-outer, .fancybox-inner {
    position: relative;
}

.fancybox-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fancybox-type-iframe .fancybox-inner {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.fancybox-error {
    color: #444;
    font: 14px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-image, .fancybox-iframe {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.fancybox-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
    background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
}

#fancybox-loading {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -22px;
    margin-left: -22px;
    background-position: 0 -108px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8060;
}

#fancybox-loading div {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url('fancybox_loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
}

.fancybox-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -18px;
    right: -18px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent url('blank.gif'); /* helps IE */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: 8040;
}

.fancybox-prev {
    left: 0;
}

.fancybox-next {
    right: 0;
}

.fancybox-nav span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 34px;
    margin-top: -18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 8040;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.fancybox-prev span {
    left: 10px;
    background-position: 0 -36px;
}

.fancybox-next span {
    right: 10px;
    background-position: 0 -72px;
}

.fancybox-nav:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-tmp {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* Overlay helper */

.fancybox-lock {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.fancybox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 8010;
    background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
}

.fancybox-overlay-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Title helper */

.fancybox-title {
    visibility: hidden;
    font: normal 13px/20px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: none;
    z-index: 8050;
}

.fancybox-opened .fancybox-title {
    visibility: visible;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -35px;
    z-index: 8050;
    text-align: center;
}

.fancybox-title-float-wrap .child {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -100%;
    padding: 2px 20px;
    background: transparent; /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
       -moz-border-radius: 15px;
            border-radius: 15px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #222;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.fancybox-title-outside-wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.fancybox-title-inside-wrap {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.fancybox-title-over-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

    </style>    

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#regForm').click(function() {
                $.fancybox({
                        'href' : '/officer_registration.htm'
                    });

                return false;
            });

            $('#pic').click(function() {
                $.fancybox({
                        'href' : 'http://en.gtwallpaper.com/fondecran/chiens/chiens_01.jpg'
                    });

                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>


  <title>Crime Track Application</title>



  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello :: Spring Application Test</h1>
    <p>Greetings Darindra Ramdhanie 4</p>


    <!--  <a href="login.htm">Login</a></br> -->    
    <!-- <a href="officer_registration.htm">Register</a></br>  -->

    <!-- <a class="fancybox" href="login.htm">Light Box login</a></br>  -->

    <a id="regForm" class="fancybox" href="officer_registration.htm">Light Box Registration</a></br>

    <!-- <a id ="pic" class="fancybox" href="http://en.gtwallpaper.com/fondecran/chiens/chiens_01.jpg" >dog</a>  This picture works presently-->


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the view/controller portion working without the lightbox? If not, get that working first. Then use the url that you'd use to call the form for displaying in the lightbox. I bet lightbox gives you an option of specifying a url for display. Also, is there an basic example of round trip interaction with php backend? Use that to extrapolated implementation in you spring app. I'd suggest get some code going and come back for more when you get stuck.

**EDIT:**
It does seem to support external urls, see #4 [here](http://fancybox.net/blog)
It will take 'href' as a parameter.

**EDIT 2:**

```
$('.fancybox').click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
            'href' : 'officer_registration.htm'
        });

    return false;
});
```

... not sure though if it needs an absolute url.

EDIT 3:

Per [their examples](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)  the href that you try to call fancybox on, needs to tell it that outside content needs to be displayed in an iframe: class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" in your case.

Comment: an update was made with my progress. The form works but doesnt come up in the lightbox. Yes i have the view/controller portion working without the lightbox

Comment: What browser are testing this with? Any errors, server or client side?

Comment: i am using firefox and i used firebug i didn't see any errors. when i clicked on the link it took me to the page but not in the lightbox

Comment: I'd first remove duplicate calls to jQuery lib, (you have 2 of them), then remove jq UI, etc. Seems like it's not firing at all. Strip down the page to bare minimums and get that working first. Then start adding stuff one at a time. Right now I can't spot any other issues.

Comment: i did this and still it doesn't execute in the lightbox are you aware if fancybox and support forms ?

Comment: i forgot to mention the pictures lightbox are working its only the form thats not working

Comment: this means i wont be able to achieve this ?

Comment: i have tried this in many ways full url even tried to do a call to google.com only the picture loads with the call not the form

Comment: ... update your code with the latest one you tried, especially the call to the url, etc. At this point I'd comment out other call to fancybox except for the form one.

Comment: you still have 2 call to jQery, one 1.8.1 and the other 1.8.2, pick one. And why the <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %> above doc type? What's in that?

Comment: i really though jquery.min.js and jquery-1.8.2.js were two separate CND's and both were required. <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/include.jsp" %>  is a header i was creating to include in my page it just contains tag libs

Comment: those are 2 different jQuery libs, one older and minified and the newer one is just uncompressed. So you really should use just one. At this point get rid of the first code sample, and instead add generated code, just to see what your browser has to work with.

Comment: ... well, I hate to say it at this point, but it's become a debugging project. Next i'd try 'walking back' and trying to get one their examples with an external url working. Something's amiss with the way you're calling it if everything else works. Do you really get a bunch of dots .......... on your page where the js is ;-)

Comment: no i dont all the js code couldnt fit so i just used '....' can you point me to an example of a light box that calls a form i am looking however i am not getting any.

Comment: ... not really, I'd look at their examples that come with the zip file. (I assume the examples would be there). Hm, if there's that much js that not good either. To make this work there should be just the call to fancybox. Nothing else. That's where the whole puzzle might be residing at the moment.

Comment: i tried a simple form using a modification of the demo in the zip file and same results. I created a simple form with two text boxes and a button and called it and same thing happens. It loads images however great

Comment: ... you need to be able to make that simple example work then. Start a new question just for that and make sure to post the relevant js calls to fancybox.